# What is the maximum time it will take to open a combination lock?

Tags: combinatorics

You have a barrel lock with $4$ wheels, each of which has $6$ numbers. If you can try one combination every three seconds, what is the maximum time (in hours, minutes, and seconds) it will take you to open the lock?

If there are $6$ numbers on each wheel, it's $6 \times 6 \times 6 \times 6 = 1296$ for the number of possibilities, right? I don't really know. But then if that is right how would I translate into minutes and seconds etcetera.

Comment: How many possible lock combinations are there?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You have posted a large number of questions recently that seem like mathcounts or AMC questions. I don't think this is the best use of this website; consider going on the AOPS website for similar problems and solutions. Their database is quite good and quite extensive

Comment: You are correct that there are $6^4 = 1296$ possible combinations.  Multiplying that by $3$ will give you the number of seconds it takes to try all the combinations.  There are $60$ seconds in a minute and $60^2 = 3600$ seconds in an hour.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig   I tried this and got 3888 seconds, 64.8 minutes, and 1.08 hours, but it was still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are six choices for each of the four wheels, there are indeed $6^4 = 1296$ possible combinations to try.  Since each combination takes $3$ seconds to try, trying all the combinations takes $3 \cdot 1296 = 3888$ seconds, as you found.

There are $60$ seconds in a minute and $60^2 = 3600$ seconds in an hour.  To determine the number of hours, minutes, and seconds, use division with remainder.  First, we find the number of complete hours and the number of additional seconds.
$$3888~\text{s} = 3600~\text{s} + 288~\text{s} = 1~\text{h} + 288~\text{s} \tag{1}$$
Next, we find the number of minutes and additional seconds in $288~\text{s}$.
$$288~\text{s} = 4 \cdot 60~\text{s} + 48~\text{s} = 4~\text{m} + 48~\text{s} \tag{2}$$
Substituting our result from equation 2 into equation 1 yields
$$3888~\text{s} = 1~\text{h} + 4~\text{m} + 48~\text{s}$$